# Responsive Sharepoint Input Text Fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, inputformtextbox, responsive

I have designed the online **SharePoint** responsive with the media queries, And when i tested it with a mobile all are working perfectly without this textbox input fields issue. The issue is when i touch the textbox in the *news-feed* the view become zoomed and the alignments of the **CSS** components become unstable and when i touch the *search* textbox same happens and with that the keyboard comes and disappears suddenly, simply cant input values. I have tried the zooming disabled feature by modifying the meta tag but it doesn't worked. Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Since it is zooming, your media queries are being applied again and messing up your alignment. One way to fix this would be to use fixed width for different media queries so that zooming doesn't affect it.

Comment: so it means that i have to use "px" values for width and height right ? not %

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can define different px values for different media queries and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: but that will be more complex because for the responsiveness % is more efficient than including px values for width right ?

Comment: Not in all cases. Media queries are designed for just that. If you are using %, media queries are not needed since it'll automatically resize based on the viewport width. For fixed width, you can define different widths for different viewport  sizes. If you look at Bootstrap container css, they have defined fixed width for different media queries to make it responsive.

Comment: Since you might have designed the widths in % etc, when zooming happens widths are calculated relative to that which likely messes up. Anyway, fixed width is just a suggestion.

Comment: Also, give this a read: https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/

Comment: tried the method in the article you included here by replacing the media query "px" values of widths to "em", also i tried the fixed width values that you mentioned, by applying it only to the search box input nothing happened, same scenario occurs. Are there any other solution other than this ? this happens only when viewing the content in portrait mode, in landscape mode the issue is not there, keyboard comes smoothly and no any zooming happens.

Comment: BTW, what happens when you click on the search box? A screenshot might help here. Can you pls paste a link here?

Comment: for the search box issue i have to video record so ill post that later , here is the screen shot of the news feed text box when i touch to input values http://pasteboard.co/1F0bewO6.jpg  http://pasteboard.co/1F0imMh6.jpg

Comment: sorry i couldn't find any screen recorders for my phone so ill describe what is happening, when i touch the search box the keyboard comes with zooming and vanishes suddenly, simply i cant input anything there , when sudden zooming happens i can see that the alignments are going wild

Comment: Please help me to solve this still i haven't got any solution for this issue :(

Comment: OK. Instead of using mobile to check a mobile site, try using Chrome. This way you'll know exactly what is going wrong. http://www.sitepoint.com/better-responsive-website-testing-google-chrome/

Comment: i tried a lot in there, usually i test the results with the desktop browser. The zooming and focusing doesn't happens in desktop browsers, its only happens with the mobile browsers, its a function of normal smartphone browsers i think

Comment: I think I know what is happening. Your Newsfeed div is fixed and is not expanding with the search box. Check that first

Comment: Also check how the div stays fixed. Maybe try replicating the same styles to textbox as well.